# $_SESSION variables not passing between files

Tags: php, session

I've got a login script that puts user details into session variables. Today I moved the website to a new host, and now my coding doesn't work. This is the best I can do, and it still doesn't work

main_login.php:

```
(script above here gets all the $info from the database. So far it is working)
if($count==1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $info['username'];
    $_SESSION['given'] = $info['given_name'];
    $_SESSION['family'] = $info['family_name'];
    $_SESSION['profile'] = $info['profile'];
    $_SESSION['adultchild'] = $info['adultchild'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $info['id'];
    header("location:welcome.php");
}
```

welcome.php:

```
// Check if session is not registered , redirect back to main page. 
// Put this code in first line of web page. 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

The trouble is when I print any of the session variables nothing happens. I've even tried doing a `var_dump($_SESSION)` but it comes up as an empty array. Frankly I've spent all day on this and am stuck.

Comment: Check your configuration if session support is enabled, and check your cookies, if a `PHPSESSID` cookie is being set at all.

Comment: probably it doesn't enter your if($count==1), no other explanation for array being empty

Comment: You likely have the cookie domain set wrong so the cookie is being sent, but browser refuses to accept/send the cookie back as the domain is not the correct one.

Comment: how do I change stuff to do with cookies? As in like the cookie domain and that

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']));
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

change to:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
//                               ^ typing mistake
    header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

Comment: ah sorry just checked and that was a typo from when i was copying it to here